# My postgresql database does not respond to python commands

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I am applying SQL commands with Python (PyCharm), and for some reason that I can't understand the following method can't be executed:

```
def save_to_db(self):
    connection = psycopg2.connect(user='postgres', password='valid', database='learning', host='localhost')
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        cursor.execute('INSERT INTO users (email, first_name, last_name) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)',(self.email, self.first_name, self.last_name))
    print('here save_to_db')    # as a trace
    connection.commit()
    connection.close()
```

It is called from the following script:

```
from user import User    # the class where the methods are
my_user = User('email@email.com', 'first name', 'last name', None)  # in the database there is auto-increment for the primary key (4th argument)
my_user.save_to_db()
```

Neither the database is updated, nor the print command I use as a trace is giving any outcome in the run window of pycharm. Even if I use a non valid password, instead of an error I get "Process finished with exit code 0". However that method worked once, the first time I applied it, allowing me to save some data in the database. Since then I get response from the database only through pgadmin4.
I would be glad if I could get some help about this issue. Thank you in advance.

There may be some more details in the previous thread I raised for the same issue:
[python-postgresql, seems to be connected but no respond](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53715813/python-postgresql-seems-to-be-connected-but-no-respond)

EDIT: I'm placing the full code of the application.
The file with the User class is following:

```
import psycopg2


class User:
def __init__(self, email, first_name, last_name, id):
    self.email = email
    self.first_name = first_name
    self.last_name = last_name
    self.id = id

def __repr__(self):
    return "<User {}>".format(self.email)

def save_to_db(self):
    with psycopg2.connect(user='postgres', password='valid', database='learning', host='localhost')
        with connection.cursor() as cursor:
            cursor.execute('INSERT INTO users (email, first_name, last_name) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)', (self.email, self.first_name, self.last_name))
    print('here save_to_db')    # as a trace to define wether or not the method is executed


@classmethod
def load_from_db_by_email(cls, email):
    with psycopg2.connect(user='postgres', password='valid', database='learning', host='localhost') as connection:
        with connection.cursor() as cursor:
            cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM users WHERE email=%s', (email,))
            user_data = cursor.fetchone()
            return cls(user_data[1], user_data[2], user_data[3], user_data[0])
```

And here is following the file which is calling both of the two methods.

```
from user import User

saveToDb = 1 # 1 to save, else to load

if saveToDb==2:
    print('save')    # a print method again as a trace
    my_user = User('email@email.com', 'first_name', 'last_name', None)
    my_user.save_to_db()
else:
    print('load')    # a print method again as a trace
    my_user = User.load_from_db_by_email('email@email.com')
    print(my_user)
```

Again I'm using a print method as a trace, and what it comes is that also the code that's calling the methods is not executed.

Comment: Is there perhaps some exception generated you haven't noticed, or are handling but not reporting?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like an exception is being generated and you are not seeing it.  Or some code that is wrapping this function is catching it with `except:` and not reporting it.

How about this varient:

EDIT: Added a couple of print()s.

```
def save_to_db(self):
    print("DEBUG: ENTER save_to_db()");
    rc = False
    my_database = 'learning'
    try:
        connection = psycopg2.connect(user='postgres', password='zSvG3$', database=my_database, host='localhost')
    except Exception as e:
        print("Unable to connect to [" + my_database + "] - " + str(e))
        connection = None

    if (connection != None):
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        try:
            cursor.execute('INSERT INTO users (email, first_name, last_name) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)',  (self.email, self.first_name, self.last_name))
            connection.commit()
            connection.close()
            rc = True
        except Exception as e:
            print("INSERT FAILED - "+str(e))
    print("DEBUG: EXIT save_to_db()");
    return rc
```

Comment: I am afraid that again nothing is reported. Thanks for responding

Comment: Also the code that is calling the method does not give any outcome, even if I place a print method as the following: 
from user import User / 
print('save') / 
my_user = User('email@email.com', 'first_name', 'last_name', None) / 
my_user.save_to_db()

Comment: Do you have another function of the same name declared later in the class?  I bet it does, and that's what's being called.

Comment: It was my fault that I didn't make it clear. In the previous thread I was talking about two methods (save to db and load from it), but I place only the code for the two versions of one of them. Which none of the two was able to save to the db. Just the same was the outcome with the load method, either with the commit() version, or with the 'with' for the connection version. I mean again there wasn't any respond for the respective function. As I'm trying to make it clear even now, I'm going to add the full code.

Comment: I just saw the edited code. I tried it, but again not any report in the run window.